# Change font after createTextNode()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to change the font of element created by the createTextNode() function:

```
var s = document.createTextNode(item.text);
s.setAttribute("font size") = -1;
elem.appendChild(s);
```

In my code I get error on Firebug:

> s.setAttribute is not a function

How can I change a font of created element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't specify font on **text nodes**, you do so on the parent **element** - in your case:

```
elem.style.fontSize = "20px";
```

If you don't wish to change the font size for the entire parent element, you can create a `<span>` element to wrap around the text node:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.style.fontSize = "20px";
span.appendChild(s);
elem.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: why not just wrap it around another div?

Answer (score 5):

createTextNode creates a [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1312295772) node that has only one method: splitText. [setAttribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68F082) is a method of the DOM Core that is implemented by the Element interface (i.e. not text nodes).

Generally, you should avoid setAttribute as it has numerous quirks and setting the related DOM property is faster and more reliable.

In any case, there is no "fontSize" attribute specified in HTML 4.01 for text nodes so you can't expect browsers to implement it. Text nodes inherit their style from their parent element, so if you want to set the font size of some text, wrap it in an element:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var span = document.createElement('span');

  // Set DOM property
  span.style.fontSize = '200%';
  span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('hey'));

  // Add to document
  document.body.appendChild(span);
};
```

But in general you are better off to define the style in a class and attach that to the span.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use inline css. Never tried this with a textnode though

```
setAttribute('style', 'font-size:-1;');
```