# How to apply CSS directly to DOM TextNodes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I assign `text-align:center` property to `TextNode` created thro' `DOM` node. I added this `TextNode` directly to `body`(without using any `<div>` components).

```
 var Text = document.createTextNode("Welcome");
 Text.style.text-align = 'center';
```

Comment: First it will be Text.style.textAlign and not text-align.

Comment: Second, there is no style attribute for a text node and hence not possible like that.

Comment: Check out this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549114/change-font-after-createtextnode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. CSS only applies to elements, not text nodes.

You'll need to wrap the text node in an element, or use an element directly:

```
var text = document.createElement("p");
text.textContent = "Welcome";
text.style.textAlign = "center";
```

...though you might as well use a heading element for this.

Comment: I'm using firefox and Im not getting innerText to work, and here its claimed its not supported in Firefox, http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=12605

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson My apologies - the standard form is `textContent`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript the CSS styles get converted to camel casing. Like this...

```
Text.style.textAlign = 'center';
```

So,

`text-align` becomes `textAlign`, `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Just give the Same textAlign property to the element in which the text-node is being wrapped.
You cannot apply styling to a Text-Node. You can apply styling to elements which are wrapped around the Text-Node and thus the CSS style gets applied to everything that's inside that wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply CSS to text nodes.So its better to create the text inside a

element.
you can do it by two jQuery functions.

Using `.css()`

```
var Text = $("<p>welcome</p>").css("textAlign","center");
```

Using `.addClass()`

first write a style in your css that will be applied on cls class as,

```
.cls {text-align: center}
```

then add this class to your newly created element in your script as,

```
var Text = $("<p>Welcome</p>").addClass("cls");
```