# Styling each letter in a String with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to figure out a way to style every separate letter in a string with javascript but I'm not sure what I can do.

```
for(var i =0; i < someText.length; i++){
    someText[i].style.color = getRandomColor();
}
```

This is what I've been trying, but this doesnt work. Any Ideas?

Comment: You would need to build a new HTML string (or append new elements) where each letter was enclosed in a span tag with the corresponding style.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate, but you might find this post informative: [Change font after createTextNode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549114/change-font-after-createtextnode) Specifically: "You don't specify [styles] on *text nodes*, you do so on the parent *element*".