# How to apply css to an element which does not have a tag belonging to itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's assume there is a html which looks like

```
<div id="a"> 
  123
  <span id="b">456</span>
  789
</div>
```

I want to apply css only to 123, not to 456
If I apply css to top div (id=a), it will influence 123 and 456 because `<span id="b">456</span>` is also belonging to top div (id=a)

Adding span around 123 is not an option because html itself is not under my control.

What I did was trying to get 123 like this.

```
const node123 = getElementById('a').childNodes[0]
node123.style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

But the code failed with the message that "TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined.

I found text element node (node123) does not have style.

Instead, following code works good.

```
const node456 = getElementById('a').childNodes[1]
node456.style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

I think that it works because it is not text element but a node with tag (span in this case)

How can I apply css to node123 without adding span tag around node123, which is text element without tag?

Thanks

Comment: set as `data-tag="your tag value"` and use pseudo classes to show the tag. ;)

Comment: It entirely depends on what CSS you are trying to apply. Some properties will be inherited by the child span and some can be overridden

Comment: node456.style["background-color"] = "red";

Comment: Do you want 789 to be affected too?

Comment: @AdarshMohan thanks for your comment.  Could you provide more detailed explanation or code?   Where should I add data-tag="xxx" and what should be the "xxx" value?

Comment: @Dexygen   No, I do want only 123 to be influenced.

Comment: @Paulie_D  I want to change backgroundColor.  That is the only attribute I want to apply

Comment: The only way to display partial text with different style is wrap it in it's own element. Text nodes themselves can not be styled

Comment: I know its weird to ask, but is the `123` expected to be a three digit string always?

Comment: if you can calculate the length of the required text, you can use the [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient())

Comment: @AdarshMohan   hmm.  not necessary.   It can be whatever strings, though the string is determined when the document is loaded.

Comment: @AdarshMohan   I guess I can calculate the length of the required text.  I will study linear gradient as you advised.   Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Adding span around 123 is not an option because html itself is not under my control.

Maybe not directly - but the rest of your question makes clear that you can run your own Javascript and use that to manipulate styles (including inline styles). So why not use JS to manipulate the DOM to wrap it in a `span` that you can then style?

```js
const container = document.getElementById('a');
const node123 = container.childNodes[0];
const wrapped123 = document.createElement('span');
wrapped123.appendChild(node123);
wrapped123.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
container.prepend(wrapped123);
```

```html
<div id="a"> 
  123
  <span id="b">456</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.   But still it is not an option to me, because I should not change the DOM structure.  My application should memorize the exact DOM structure as it for some reason.   I have to do it only by applying css without changing DOM.

Comment: OK, it was just a suggestion. I wasn't suggesting my above answer is good code! But I'm puzzled by the requirements - even the manipulation of the `style` attribute as you were attempting is technically "changing the DOM". I'd be interested in the exact reasons for these "rules", otherwise it's really hard to answer the question. I can understand now being able to directly change the underlying HTML content, but I don't see why, if you're allowed to add Javascript, you can't do whatever you want in that JS (within reason).

Comment: @RobinZigmond +1 from me, built my snippet around the same approach - but tried to showcase this in dynamic. And yes, you're absolutely right - unless one wants to dive deep into background styling with overlays (which still require DOM augmentation, albeit perhaps a completely isolated part of it), there's no way to apply styles to TextNodes alone.

Comment: Hmm.   After some thoughts, maybe your idea of adding span around the target could be an option.   If the code change all DOM text element without its own tag into span-added text element in advance and then remember that changed DOM as a original one, then when I apply css later, my code apply span-adding and then apply css.  It will remove DOM structure disorganization issue completely, because some DOM structure changes happen always.        You may not understand my comment because I did not fully explain my situation, but it is true that you gave me some hints.  Thanks

Comment: No problem - you're right that I don't fully understand your situation, but happy to have perhaps been of some help

Answer (score 0):

[TextNodes are not meant to be styled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5549366/1229023). If all you want is to change some text-related properties, you indeed can proceed and modify the styling based on some `:not()` rules. All the box-related properties (and backgroundColor among them) will still be applied to the whole `<div>`.

Still, there's a way, and that snippet demonstrates it:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.getElementById('a');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const isPristine = div.classList.contains('pristine');
  isPristine ? wrapTextNodes(div) : unwrapTextNodes(div);
  div.classList.toggle('pristine');
});

function wrapTextNodes(div) {
  const childNodes = Array.from(div.childNodes);
  childNodes.forEach(node => {
    if (node.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) return;
    if (!/\S/.test(node.data)) return;
    const wrapperSpan = document.createElement('span');
    wrapperSpan.classList.add('wrapper');
    wrapperSpan.appendChild(
      div.replaceChild(wrapperSpan, node));
  });
}

function unwrapTextNodes(div) {
  div.querySelectorAll('wrapper').forEach(wrapper => {
    div.replaceChild(wrapper.childNodes[0], wrapper);
  });
}
```

```css
#a {
  color: green;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#a.pristine {
  background-color: pink;
}

#b, #c, #d {
  color: navy;
  background-color: white;
}

#a .wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="pristine"> 
  123
  <span id="b">456</span>
  789
  <span id="c">111</span>
  <span id="d">222</span>
</div>
<br />
<button type="button">Change it all!</button>
```

The idea is that you're able to wrap your textNodes on the fly (it may be the *last* step of rendering process) and unwrap them when necessary, with just a little bit of DOM manipulation. One has to be cautious about edge cases when doing this though; there are some issues with RTL texts, and don't even get me started about bidirectional.

There's yet another alternative to that: having a number of 'styling' elements with z-index high enough, lying over the text nodes you want to style. That's possible (some readers do it with annotations, for example), but that tends to be glitchy (one has to reapply all the overlays correctly for every layout-affecting event).